# Overlap table or figure with a note box

Tags: tables, overlap

If I have a table as such:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
        cell11 & cell12 & cell13 \\
        cell21 & cell22 & cell23 \\
        cell31 & cell32 & cell33 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

And I want a simple command to show a note with some text overlapping the table (or figure). The solution should be easy comment out (to disable and re-enable the note).

Something that looks like this:

[image]

The intent is that while working on the document, I want the resulting pdf to have something saying this figure/table is not yet completed.

I've looked at the todonotes packages, which I use for text notes, but in this case I want to overlap the table/figure with the note, not put it in the margin.

Another solution I saw was tikzpicture, but then I need to change all my figures to be contained in `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti*k*Z solution, which won't change your code much. And you can always comment/uncomment `\addnote` any time you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\addnote[3][fill=red,text width=3cm]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt](table-1){\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
        cell11 & cell12 & cell13 \\
        cell21 & cell22 & cell23 \\
        cell31 & cell32 & cell33 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}};%
    \addnote{table-1}{\underline{Note}: This table is not complete}%
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I could use that, thanks. But for every table I want to use this on, I would have to have `\tikz[...]\node[...](id){}` wrapped around it? And this id would have to be unique for every table I assume. The solution would work for figures?

Comment: @remi000 This literally works for any kind of elements. Just substitute the part inside the node (now a `tabular` by another e.g. `\includegraphics`)